# .find replacing content inside html tags

Tags: jquery

I want to sanitize html tags from my wysiwyg. I want to replace certain tags with another. This almost works only the replaceWith() is also removing the content from within the tags. I dont want to do this. I just want to replace the tags. Here is what I have so far.

Text for Testing:

```
This<div>is</div><div>a test</div><div>to clean&nbsp;</div><div>some tags</div><div><br></div>
```

Expected Result:

```
This<p>is</p><p>a test</p><p>to clean</p><p>some tags</p><p><br></p>
```

Actual Result:

```
This<p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p>
```

This is the code I am using to find and replace

```
var thebad = ["h1","h2","h3","h4","h5","h6","div"];
        var thegood = ["","","","","","","<p>"];
        for(var i = 0; i < thebad.length; i++){
            $('.content').contents().find('body').find(thebad[i]).replaceWith(thegood[i]);
        }
```

I need to figure out how to keep the text inside the html tags when i replace them.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you forgot the "ugly": `<script>` :D (just joking)

Comment: Just to point out it removes the text from inside any of the obove mentioned tags so for example <h2>Test</h2> results in a null value as it strips out the word "Test" too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var text = $("#test").html();
var replace_tags = { "<div>": "<p>", "</div>": "</p>",  "<div ": "<p "}; //edited
$.each( replace_tags, function(i,v){
     text = text.replace(new RegExp(i, 'g'),v);
});
//console.log(text);
```

Tested on:

```
<div id='test'>
    <h1>dummy text</h1>
    <div>dummy text</div>
    <h1>dummy text</h1>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <div>dummy text</div>
</div>
```

Results:

```
<h1>sadsad</h1>
<p>sadsad</p>
<h1>fsdfsd</h1>
<p>dasdasdasdsad</p>
<p>sadsad</p>
```

Comment: if a div has a style or class can it be replaced too? for example <div class="">ok</div> is resulting in <div class="">ok<p></p></div>

Comment: var replace_tags = { "<div>": "<p>", "</div>": "</p>", "<div ": "<p "};

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('div').contents().unwrap().wrap('<p />');
```

EDIT:

```
$('div').replaceWith(function(){ 
    return $("<p />").append($(this).contents()); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, the result is a null

Comment: It outputs the same result This<p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p>

Comment: Thanks for the responses and efforts!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div").replaceWith(function() {
    var $div = $(this);
    return $("<p />")
        //.attr('class', $div.attr('class')) // uncomment if you need to give back same class value
        .html($div.html());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Gustonez

Comment: and? it doesn't work? this is the proper jquery way to do it.